# WindowStatupLocation = CenterScreen is not working correctly in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In the properties for the parent window I set WindowStatupLocation=CenterScreen
In the properties for the Child window I set WindowStatupLocation=CenterOwner

on the button click in the parent window if i show child window, the child window position is not center owner.

Is this is a bug in WPF or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the owner of the child window to the parent window.

```
WindowChild windowChild = new WindowChild();
windowChild.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner; // you can set this in xaml
windowChild.Owner = this; // this is parent window
windowChild.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What if , If I showing the dialog from my viewmodel. I mean to say , How can I set the owner then ??

Comment: A true VM should not be showing dialogs. Instead, add a bool property in the VM that the parent window will watch. When the VM sets it to true/false the parent window will show/hide the child window.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to explicitly set the **ChildWindow.Parent** property with the window that will be its parent ?